# how obtain android version on .config .in cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I need to get the android version on the angularJS ".config" method. I need to know that number before than call a specific service.
if i get the number on the ".run" method, the service is already initialized

i want to define the type of transport, depending of the android version

this is my service:

```
var app = angular.module('starter');

app.service('SocketService', function () {

    return io.connect('http://54.221.207.114:3001',{'transports':['websocket']});

});
```

Comment: It seems relatively simple to retrieve the OS version in Angular. Have you tried that? Something similar to what's described here: http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/09/21/detect-os-browser-and-device-in-angularjs/

Comment: @Chris .I need to know the android versio in the "config" method, not in a controller, because the service is initialized and need the version number before that

Comment: @Chris i know how obtain the android version, but i don't know how obtain in the config method or in a place before a service load